# Minikube: unable to pull image from DockerHub (public repo)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, dockerhub

I'm sporting a fresh **Minikube** install on an **ArchLinux** box, using **Docker** as the **Minikube** driver.

I started the **minikube** "cluster" using the `minikube start` command. `docker container ls` tells us it's up and running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
d86070af0c21   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes   127.0.0.1:49162->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49161->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49160->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49159->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49158->32443/tcp   minikube
```

I'm trying to run a simple **nginx** pod, using this command: `kubectl run my-nginx --image nginx`

Since I'm pulling a public image from a public repo, I would expect I don't need any authentication. But the `describe pod` sub-command shows:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  47s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/my-nginx to minikube
  Normal   BackOff    31s                kubelet            Back-off pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     31s                kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    19s (x2 over 46s)  kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     4s (x2 over 31s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed     4s (x2 over 31s)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

When I try to **curl** the URL found in the error message from inside the **minikube** container, it shows that authentication is needed:

```
patres@arch:~$ minikube ssh                                                                        

docker@minikube:~$ curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

When I try to pull that very image from host using `docker pull nginx` command, the image gets pulled, no auth required.

I also tried to create a **kubernetes** secret this way, then launching the pod using YAML with that secret, but it was to no avail.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ --docker-username=myusername --docker-password=mypass --docker-email=my@email.com
```

Finally, it seems like the issue might not be unique to **DockerHub**, since if I follow
the official **minikubes** [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) and launch the default `hello-minikube` deployment:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
```

I get the same `ImagePullBackOff` error:

```
$ kubectl get pod hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-zdzz2                                           
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-zdzz2   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          6m11s
```

Comment: Same here. Quite annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved by one of these actions (not sure by which exactly):

- terminating my VPN connection
- deleting the **minikube** container and image
- rebooting my computer
- starting anew with `minikube start`

Comment: I would guess it was the VPN, the auth to a repository would be the point of failure

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right way or the solution to do things, but here is what worked for me..

```
minikube cache add <dockerhub username>/<repo name>:<version optional>
```

This worked on localhost as I had the docker image on my local machine.
Ofcourse all the configurations were in my .yml files with imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent. So it did not pull the image if it was not present. But we are not exactly trying to achieve that. The correct solution would require the kubernetes to pull the image each time the service is restarted